# PHP protection of GET parameters

Tags: php, security, get

OK consider this url:

```
example.com/single.php?id=21424
```

It's pretty obvious to you and i that the PHP is going to take the id and run it through a mysql query to retrieve 1 record to display it on the page.

Is there anyway some malicious hacker could mess this url up and pose a security threat to my application/mysql DB?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Of COURSE. Anyone could write whatever they want.

Comment: Regardless of the security aspect, it's also not a good application design to expose database-internal identifiers. Most objects in the database have a name or title, which should preferred as URL parameters when feasible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course, never ever ever consider a user entry (_GET, _POST, _COOKIE, etc) as safe.

Use mysql_real_escape_string php function to sanitize your variables: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

About SQL injections : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Even _SERVER isn't always safe (e.g., HTTP_REFERER)

Comment: Sure, theses are only examples :)

Answer (score 2):

All depends on the filtering you explicitely (with [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for instance) or implictely (by using prepared statements for instance) use.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is Sql injection 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection